# Camunda Run - Override/Change configuration settings

Tags: kubernetes-helm, camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm working on deploying Camunda RUN 7.19 on an AKS cluster using the Helm chart provided by the community. Currently, I'm starting it with the default configuration, and then, I'm manually editing the default.yml file within the configuration folder using the shell and vim to enable certain security parameters (e.g., basic auth). I don't want to use the production.yml file at the moment.

The problem I'm facing is that when a pod restarts, my changes to the file are lost. How can I make these changes persistent? I tried using a ConfigMap, but since the Helm version doesn't support subpaths, I can't override a single file. I believe this is a fairly common scenario. What have you done in such cases, and what path would you recommend I follow?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to override the application.properties with an environment variable named SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON, for instance:

```
az container create --resource-group rg-camunda --name camunda-run
--image camunda/camunda-bpm-platform:run-latest --dns-name-label robs-camunda --ports 8080 --protocol TCP --cpu 1 --memory 0.5
--environment-variables SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"camunda.bpm.run.auth.enabled":"true"}'
```

src: https://medium.com/@emsbach/deploying-camunda-bpm-to-azure-container-service-via-cli-in-5-minutes-cab7fd14e50c